# Allow some OutOfStock products to be visible

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this problem / demand from client:
Show all products with stock > 0
Show also all products with stock = 0 and custom checkbox '_show_zero_stock' is set to true

But provided code in functions.php doesnt work as described.

I think issue is only in 'WHERE TO USE' condition '! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_search' but i need your help. I tried meta_query but wp with ~1s response has after meta_query 20s pageload.

Wordpress 5.2.1, Woocommerce 3.5.5, Theme: Flastome (child)
versions will be upgraded to latest.

- if '_show_zero_stock' checkbox in product is checked, then _show_zero_stock exists and value = 'yes'
- join postmeta by post_id
- add query to filter products by condition

```php
function custom_posts_join($join, $q){
 if( ! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_search) {// No global $wp_query here
    global $wpdb;
    $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as meta_1 ON $wpdb->posts.ID = meta_1.post_id";
 }
 return $join;
}

function filter_function_name_2925( $where, $q ){ // No global $wp_query here
    if( ! is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_search) {
        $where .= " AND ((meta_1.meta_key = '_stock' AND meta_1.meta_value > 0) OR (meta_1.meta_key = '_hide_zero_stock' AND meta_1.meta_value = 'yes' ))"; 
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_join' , 'custom_posts_join', 10, 2);
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_function_name_2925', 10, 2 );
```

Expected result - 
show products with stock > 0 (AND)
show products with stock = 0 which has checked _show_zero_stock

Which parts should be affected: 
categories, search and ajax search [front end]

Which parts should not be affected: 
product pages - product URL must be accessible and visible regardless of _show_zero_stock value

I tried this with meta_query. horrible performance impact:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'show_out_of_stock_products' );
function show_out_of_stock_products( $q ) {
$meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
    $meta_query[] = array(
    'cache_results' => false,
        'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => '_stock',
                    'compare' => '>',
                    'value' => '0',
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_stock',
                        'compare' => '=',
                        'value' => '0',
                        'type'  => 'numeric',
                    ),
                    array(
                            'key' => '_show_zero_stock',
                            'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
                        )
                )
    );
    $q->set( 'meta_query', array($meta_query) );
}
```

Comment: What hook are you using to call hide_out_of_stock_products function and is it working in all three cases ( categories, search, and ajax search) even though it is slow?

Comment: When trying the join and where hooks, does it work differently if you use is_search() with the parentheses in the "where to use" condition? I believe it needs a few more conditional checks, but maybe you can confirm that it kind of works?

Comment: @JasonB i used add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_out_of_stock_products' );

Comment: @JasobB  I tried alone is_search() , $q->is_search() and also $q->is_search
if i ommit it  other pages are 404

Answer (score 0):

```
 $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => '_stock',
            'value' => 1,
            'compare' => '<'
         )
      ),
      'fields' => 'ids',
   );`enter code here`
    $product_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
   $product_ids = implode( ",", $product_ids );
This will return all out of stock products
```

Comment: Thanks but i need also all products with stock more than one and if stock is zero i need to check if _show_zero_stock is checked (value yes)